# What was the most succesful military dictatorship in the last 200 years in terms of economic growth?

Tags: economy, dictatorship

Military dictatorships are controlled by military officers. I am wondering which military dictatorship was the most economically successful, you can use any figure like GDP growth, GDP per capita, GDP (PPP), etc. to base your argument. I don't think the current Chinese government was a military dictatorship. Maybe Mao's government, but not the government that followed, so I am guessing China wouldn't count.

Comment: Pinochet's is a strong candidate. Though it was gis undoing, as a liberal economy entrains the liberal politics - very Marxist reason that Marxists hate to acknowledge in this case.

Comment: @RogerV.: That's a common myth. Chile GDP per capita (2011$): 1973: $7,911, 1990: $10,203. (Same source as my answer below.) Average annual growth 1973–90 = (10203/7911)^(1/17)-1 ≈ 1.5%. See also ["Pinochet's economic policy is vastly overrated"](https://www.noahpinion.blog/p/pinochets-economic-policy-is-vastly). (One reason for this persistent myth is the influence of Milton Friedman and his disciples who perpetuate the myth.)

Comment: @user103496 as compared to what? Your answer gives just one example - not enough for *overrated*/*myth* claim.

Comment: @RogerV.: 1.5% per annum growth is hardly "successful" or "strong" (if you are at all familiar with GDP growth figures)

Comment: @RogerV.: Over the same period (1973–90), the US (a much richer country which should not be expected to grow as rapidly as poorer countries) enjoyed 2.0% per capita GDP growth per annum. Yet no one spoke of a "US miracle" (whereas Friedman coined the myth of the ["Miracle of Chile"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miracle_of_Chile)).

Comment: @user103496 in comparison to who? You want to say that Chile growth doesn't match that of the US or Europe (not so impressive lately) or that of African countries, or that of the countries in similar situation? (If you are familiar with GDP growth figures ;) )

Comment: @RogerV.: A country in a similar situation (also a military dictatorship around the same period) was South Korea, which enjoyed 7.6% per capita GDP growth per annum in 1961–87. So, no, Pinochet's is not a strong candidate.

Comment: @user103496 *a much richer country which should not be expected to grow as rapidly as poorer countries* - that's what I expected - your only point of reference is the US, and you do not take into account that it had had decades if stability, while Chile was in depression. I hope you learn the lesson.

Comment: @user103496 yes, your example of South Korea is strong, and I do not dispute it. But It is just one data point, which does not justify your sweeping claims in response to my comment. I suggest doing more research for your answer and including more data.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

South Korea 1961–87

- 1961 GDP per capita $1,606
- 1987 GDP per capita $10,865
- Average annual growth (10865/1606)^(1/26)-1 ≈ 7.63%.

(Source: [Maddison Project Database (MPD) 2020](https://www.rug.nl/ggdc/historicaldevelopment/maddison/data/mpd2020.xlsx). 2011$.)